# How to make images larger in Materialize framework Parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design

I'm new to frameworks (used a tiny bit of bootstrap before) and have begun building a site with the [materialize framework](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html).

As you can see on that link, there is a Parallax framework, which I would like to use. The trouble is, when I swap my images in, it's cutting off more than I would like. Does anybody know how to solve this?

When I use google dev tools, there is a `translate3D` attribute, for which I can edit the Y value which does the trick. I guess this is in the materialize.js file line 1154:

```
$img.css('transform', "translate3D(-50%," + parallax + "px, 0)");
```

but I can't figure out where the parallax variable is being set.

Answer (score 0):

Try and change the size of the image in `<img height="" width="">`
. It won't cut that much. Or if you want to increase the size of the parallax image container just use

```
.parallax-container{
    height:
}
```

PS:
Always use high-res pictures when using parallax.